# Split column into several columns based on column value

Tags: r, dataframe, split

How do I split a data frame with 2 columns into a data frame with several columns, based on the value in column 1? For example:

```
n value
1 53
1 12
1 26
1 10
2 3
2 16
2 18
2 24
```

Should become:

```
n value n.1 value.1
1 53    2 3
1 12    2 16
1 26    2 18
1 10    2 24
```

The resulting column names are unimportant. There will always be an equal number of rows for n = 1, n = 2 etc.

Comment: it sounds like you want to pivot your table, did you look for pivoting solutions in R?

Comment: I'll try to answer when I can but look into the `reshape2` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can call data frame on a `split` by the column `n`:

```
do.call('data.frame', split(df, df$n))
#  X1.n X1.value X2.n X2.value
#1    1       53    2        3
#2    1       12    2       16
#3    1       26    2       18
#4    1       10    2       24

#Or as @Imo added
data.frame(split(df, df$n))
```